# Vocative comma or comma splice?

Tags: commas, vocatives

If I wanted to start a sentence with "*hey*" and follow that with someone's name, would a comma go after the name too? Here's what I mean:

1:

> "*Hey, Thomas, I'm staying home today.*"

2:

> "*Hey, Thomas. I'm staying home today.*"

Is it wrong to have the comma after Thomas?

Comment: How about *"Hey, Thomas!"*? Take your pick. It's a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put a comma both before and after the name.

I was taught this little trick: if you remove the word between the commas ("Hey, I'm staying home today.") and it's still a complete sentence, then the 2-comma rule applies.